# Shiny Dashboard does not scroll usign 2 big plots

Tags: r, shiny, scroll, shinydashboard

I am creating a simple ShinyDashboard. The main page contains 2 plots too big to be visualized one next to each other and so, I placed the second one below the first. The problem is that the App does NOT scroll down. The second plot is cut at half. I cannot scroll down in any of the other tabs...

How can I make my app to scroll on every tab ? Below I attach a simple example of my code.

```
dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "total_barplot_tab",
                    fluidRow(
                            box(plotlyOutput("total_barplot"),width = "100%"),
                            box(plotlyOutput("total_barplot_2"),width = "100%")))))
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want them to occupy the same row you have to call column within fludRow and put the width to 6, since 12 is the max. If you want them to be in different rows you have to call two different fluidRow arguments each with their own box

Comment: Im getting the same output... My problem is whatever combination I do, none of the tabs is scrolling...
dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "total_barplot_tab",
                    fluidRow(box(plotOutput("total_barplot"),width = "100%")),
                    fluidRow(box(plotOutput("total_barplot_2"),width = "100%")))

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is the combination (fluidpage, fluidrow, fillpage) I cannot scroll in any of the tabs.
[Output don't scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nheJy.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to add your comments and complementary information accordingly (comment or part of the question). Not as answer.